# Is there any literature on a closed-form/analytical solution for American option prices with use of Chaos Theory?

Tags: option-pricing, american-options

I found the following paper which uses homotopy analysis for a closed-form solution. Does it have direct/apparent connections with chaos theory?

http://bfi.cl/assets/zhao-wong-2006---a-closed-form-solution-to-american-options-under-general-diffusions.pdf